# Grafana Loki Parsing and Aggregating over Labels - LogQL

Tags: prometheus, grafana-loki, logql

I have logs coming from repositories into grafana (loki).
I am trying to get the number of repositories (that have the msg="Repository finished") for a given duration of, say 6h"

I used these queries but they don't deliver any results

```
sum by (repository) (sum_over_time ({job=~"$cronjob", job_name=~"$job"} | json  | durationMs != "" | unwrap durationMs | __error__="" [6h] ))
```

the same for this query:

```
sum by (repository) (sum_over_time ({job=~"$cronjob", job_name=~"$job"} | json  | durationMs != "" | unwrap time| __error__="" [6h] ))
```

My logs look like this after performing `{job=~"$cronjob", job_name=~"$job"} | json | msg="Repository finished"` on them

```
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":9,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":3216,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T12:00:25.580Z","v":0}
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":9,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":3558,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T11:00:12.767Z","v":0}
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":9,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":3036,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T10:01:30.224Z","v":0}
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":8,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":3275,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T09:00:31.077Z","v":0}
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":8,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":3233,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T08:00:18.020Z","v":0}
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":9,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":3581,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T07:00:28.657Z","v":0}
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":7,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":3592,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T06:00:19.073Z","v":0}
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":10,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":8509,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T05:00:34.047Z","v":0}
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":8,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":3730,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T04:00:22.514Z","v":0}
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":9,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":3876,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T03:00:42.023Z","v":0}
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":10,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":3754,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T02:00:29.661Z","v":0}
{"name":"reno","hostname":"reno-01234","pid":10,"level":30,"logContext":"abc","repository":"abc/bmw/gmc","durationMs":3360,"msg":"Repository finished","time":"2022-08-09T01:00:17.274Z","v":0}
```

Answer (score 4):

While I don't have direct answer to Your question, I do have something similar that might help anyone who is searching for an answer.

I've decided to provide answer because it turns out that in 99% of search cases it's just `hitting a wall` - there are no examples or answers to quesion such as presented in here.

---

My goal was to `count number of entries with given string, grouped by days or months` and I've managed to get what I wanted.

See:

[image]

First of all logs example:

```
[2022-03-12T13:42:56.782023+00:00] NotifierProxyLogger.INFO: Now calling api:  {"calledMethod":"insertDiscordMessage","baseUrl":"http://...:8902","requestUri":"/api/external/discord/insert-message","dataBag":{"webhookName":"NewsFeed","messageContent":"\n**Title: ** Katarzyna Pełczyńska-Nałęcz gościnią Jacka Gądka w Porannej Rozmowie Gazeta.pl [NA ŻYWO],\n**Description: ** W poniedziałek w Porannej Rozmowie Gazeta.pl gościmy Katarzynę Płeczyńską-Nałęcz, byłą ambasadorkę Polski w Moskwie i członkinię Instytutu Strategie 2050. Rozmowę prowadzi Jacek Gądek.\n**Link: ** https://wiadomosci.gazeta.pl/wiadomosci/7,114884,28135035,katarzyna-pelczynska-nalecz-goscinia-jacka-gadka-w-porannej.html\n        ","messageTitle":"**[NEWS]** Keywords: (wezwanie armia) OR (pobór wojskowy) OR (atak na polskę)","source":"NewsFeed"}} []
```

```
[2022-03-19T12:00:03.372023+00:00] NotifierProxyLogger.INFO: Now calling api:  {"calledMethod":"insertDiscordMessage","baseUrl":"http://...","requestUri":"/api/external/discord/insert-message","dataBag":{"webhookName":"NewsFeed","messageContent":"\n**Title: ** Polska mocarstwem światowym,\n**Description: ** Wojna toczy się już 20 dzień, choć nie wiadomo dlaczego.\n**Link: ** https://wolnemedia.net/polska-mocarstwem-swiatowym/\n        ","messageTitle":"**[NEWS]** Keywords: (wezwanie armia) OR (pobór wojskowy) OR (atak na polskę) OR (atak nato) OR (wojna polska)","source":"NewsFeed"}} []
```

---

**Per day**

- **Query**: `` count_over_time({filename="/var/log/external/NAME/news-feed/notifier-proxy-logger-bridge.log"} |= `insertDiscordMessage` | regexp `(?P<timestamp>[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{1,2})` [$__interval]) ``
- **Query options**:

  - **Legend**: `{{timestamp}}`
- **Visualisation**: `Bar gauge`
- **Visualisation config**:

  - **Orientation**: `Horizontal`
  - **Calculation**: `Total`

---

**Per day for year 2023**

- **Query**: ``` count_over_time({filename="/var/log/external/NAME/news-feed/notifier-proxy-logger-bridge.log"} |= `insertDiscordMessage` |= `2023` | regexp `(\[)(?P<timestamp>2023-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{2})(T)` | timestamp != `` [$__interval]) ```
- **Query options**:

  - **Legend**: `{{timestamp}}`
- **Visualisation**: `Bar gauge`
- **Visualisation config**:

  - **Orientation**: `Vertical`
  - **Calculation**: `Total`

---

**Per day for year 2023 + total sum**

- **Query 1**: ``` count_over_time({filename="/var/log/external/NAME/news-feed/notifier-proxy-logger-bridge.log"} |= `insertDiscordMessage` |= `2023` | regexp `(\[)(?P<timestamp>2023-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{2})(T)` | timestamp != `` [$__interval]) ```
- **Query options**:

  - **Legend**: `{{timestamp}}`
- **Query 2**: ``` sum(count_over_time({filename="/var/log/external/NAME/news-feed/notifier-proxy-logger-bridge.log"} |= `insertDiscordMessage` |= `2023` | regexp `(\[)(?P<timestamp>2023-[0-9]{1,2}-[0-9]{2})(T)` | timestamp != `` [$__interval])) ```
- **Query options**:

  - **Legend**: `Total`
- **Visualisation**: `Bar gauge`
- **Visualisation config**:

  - **Orientation**: `Vertical`
  - **Calculation**: `Total`